# Why is the normal force and the tension force greater than the weight in these examples?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

A pendulum is suspended form the roof of an accelerating train. If it stays in equilibrium with respect to the train then an observer at rest will find the bob accelerating with the train. He will point out two forces that keeps the bob accelerating ($\overrightarrow{T}$ and $m\overrightarrow{g}$). So $$\overrightarrow{T}+m\overrightarrow{g} = m\overrightarrow{a}$$ And the tension force on the string is calculated as $$Tcos\theta = mg$$
This implies the tension force is greater than the weight of the mass. But isn't gravity the force that causes tension in the first place? As I understand, a component of $m\overrightarrow{g}$ pulls the string, so the string pulls back. So why is tension force greater than the weight?

Also when evaluating the bank angle of a road, we say, $$F_Ncos\theta=mg$$
Here as well, an observer at rest should find two forces only($\overrightarrow{F_N}$ and $m\overrightarrow{g}$) where the weight causes the normal force to act. Then why is the normal force the greater of the two?

Answer (score 2):

Constraint forces are whatever they need to be to help satisfy Newton's Laws of Motion.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the Tension and the Normal force are doing two 'jobs'.  They are supporting the weight of the object, but also providing a sideways acceleration.

In the case of the train the tension accelerates the mass sideways and for $F_N$ it accelerates the car towards the centre of the circle the car travels around.

The resultant ($F_N$ or $T$) force is then worked out by combining the two components with Pythagoras, and will be bigger than the weight.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no acceleration in the vertical direction magnitude of the vertical component of the tension $T$ must always be equal to the weight of the bob $mg$ as it is in both diagrams shown below.

[image]

If the bob is accelerating to the left there must be a horizontal component of the tension $t (= ma)$ and so the magnitude of the tension when the bob is accelerating $|\vec T'| = |\vec T + \vec t|$ must be greater than the magnitude of the tension $|\vec T| = T$ when the bob is not accelerating.